# Will I experience problems running a Corsair Force GT SSD in IDE mode?

Tags: ssd, ahci

I'm planning to buy the Corsair Force GT 120GB (CSSD-F120GBGT-BK) and I'm planning to use it with an older motherboard that doesn't support AHCI (ASUS P5K SE).

Will I experience any problems when running this SSD in IDE mode? A slight performance drop is acceptable.

**EDIT**

See my answer below. Conclusion: It works great.

Follow the discussion here: http://forum.corsair.com/v3/showthread.php?p=570829#post570829

---

So far so good.

Running Corsair Force GT 120GB (using FW1.3.3) on IDE. No BSOD/Freeze whatsoever.

Here are my atto benchmark results:
[image]

Comment: Please add your OS to the question.

Comment: Windows 7 64-bit with TRIM support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should not be any direct problems (instabilities or such) from running and SSD in IDE mode, assuming there are no weird firmware level bugs anywhere.

With the Microsoft IDE drivers in Windows 7 you should also get TRIM, and this avoid the performance degradation over time.

Still, there is a performance penalty to running a SSD in IDE mode. Modern SSD controllers use NCQ to populate as many controller channels at the same time as possible. It works somewhat similarly to out of order execution in cpus. NCQ is not available in IDE mode so you loose performance. The SSD will still be a lot snappier than a hard drive.

Answer (score -1):

By getting a PCIe Sata III card you can get up to the maximum supported speed of the drive.
Otherwise you'd be limited by SATA 3gbps

Comment: Not quite. If you look at the fine print of the specs for SSDs you see they apply when you run it from a native SATA controller. The Marvel usually used in the SATA expansion card is not quite as fast as the native Intel or AMD controllers and thus hurt the performance somewhat.

Answer (score -2):

There is no performance drop between AHCI and IDE. It is simply a diffrent controller hooked to the same wire leading to the disk.

Comment: There is, actually. See the benchmark here: http://ntsblog.homedev.com.au/index.php/2012/01/11/sata-3-ssd-running-on-sata-ii-benchmark/

Comment: If you attach faster disk to slower wire you get speed of slower wire... Cannot imagine how a software knob could alter cabling....

Comment: Modern SSD controllers use NCQ to populate as many controller channels at the same time as possible. It is somewhat similar to out of order execution. NCQ is not available in IDE mode so you loose significant performance.

Comment: There is no 1/100s disk revolution in SSD. NCQ has minimal effect if at all....

Comment: NCQ allows commands to be issued in parallel.  The performance benefit is easily demonstrated.  For example: http://www.pcper.com/reviews/Storage/Updated-Benchmark-Performance-SSD-Testing-AHCI-vs-IDE-or-perhaps-not